# std::isfinite on MSVC

Tags: visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, c11, cmath

The C++11 and C11 standard define the
[std::isfinite](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite)
function. Visual Studio 2012 doesn't seem to provide it as part of the
`cmath` or `math.h`, but has `amp_math.h` which
[seems to provide this function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh308288.aspx).

Is the `isfinite` interchangeable with `std::isfinite`? The
documentation doesn't talk about the behavior when called with `NAN`
and I don't have a VS compiler to test this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As *Marius* has already pointed out, the `isfinite` from `amp_math.h` is to be used in C++ AMP, which is an *MS* extension for parallel computing on many-core architectures similar to CUDA or OpenCL. And since this function can only be used in actual AMP restricted functions (usually GPU kernels) it won't be of much general use for you.

Unfortunately *VS 2012* doesn't support the C++11 math and floating point control functions. But once you recognize that you are on *VC* and implement special code for it, you can just use [`_finite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb8es7a8.aspx) (or rather `!_finite`) from `<float.h>`, which is an *MS*-secific function supported since at least *VS 2003*. But keep in mind that `_finite` only takes `double`s and thus converts any non-`double` arguments (though *VC* doesn't seem to have a proper `long double` anyway), with all its implications (while `INF`s and quiet `NaN`s should be converted without problem, I'm not sure if the trapping on a signalling `NaN` in the conversion would also have resulted from a direct call to `std::finite`).

*VC*'s standard library has [other such functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0ybw9fy.aspx) to accomodate for their lack of C++11/C99 support (like `_isnan` and the like). (Why they refuse to just remove that underscore in front of those functions and put a simple `<cfenv>` wrapper around `_controlfp` and thus get a bit nearer to complete C++11 support is a totally different question though.)

**EDIT:** Other than that, the straight-forward approach for checking `INF`s and `NaN`s might also work:

```
template<typename T> bool isfinite(T arg)
{
    return arg == arg && 
           arg != std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity() &&
           arg != -std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity();
}
```

But of course with the same implications of probably trapping for signalling `NaN`s (though I have to admit I'm not that well-versed in the intricacies of signalling `NaN`s and floating point exceptions in general).

Comment: OK, this is enough of a headache to make me just use http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/utils/fpclass.html

Comment: Perhaps this went without saying, but your `isfinite` function in your edit is very `C++`-specific.

Comment: @patrickvacek True, yet *Visual Studio* doesn't have reasonable C support anyway. I see that the answer only addresses the C++ part of the question, yet the OP seems to know both languages and should thus be able to deduce the C version of the answer if required.

Answer (score 5):

`isfinite` from `amp_math.h` can only be called from functions marked with `restrict(amp)`, which doesn't make it interchangeable, even if the behavior was the same.

Comment: Your answer is spot on, but Christian Rau's elaborations on the alternative possibilities make it the better answer. My underspecified question is at fault, not your answer.