# How to check if a value is 1.#INF0000?

Tags: c++, std, infinity

I have, in short, this code:

```
vec3 contribX1 = Sample(O, D, 0);
if (std::isinf(contribX1.x)){
    ..do something..
}
```

According to my debug I have sometimes an infinite value that is returned by the `Sample` method and I have to solve it. But before doing it, I need the tools to debug properly. So I have been looking around and I found this `std::isinf()` that should return me a bool. Unfortunately it seems I never enter that `IF` condition, even if right after I am able to check the `contribX1.x` and it actually is `1.#INF0000`. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The compiler is cl.exe.. I am using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: is [`nan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) what you're after instead?

Comment: @EdChum it doesn't work either..

Comment: Hmm how about whether it's [`!isfinite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite)?

Comment: @EdChum it works! but how come the others don't?

Comment: I've encountered a similar problem before and in my case it was do with various ways to represent positive and negative infinite values and `NaN`, using `isfinite` tests whether it's a limited value which I think is what you want to do here

Comment: Name the compiler please

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit cl.exe.. I am using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Add that crucial detail into your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`isfinite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite) to test whether the value is a valid and non-continuous (i.e. inifinite) value:

```
if (!std::isfinite(contribX1.x)){
```

should work for you, I think the issue here is that there are various values used to represent positive and negative infinite values along with `NaN`, in your situation I think using this test should be fine.

I don't know your platform but for Windows this related question is what helped me: [std::isfinite on MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580168/stdisfinite-on-msvc)

Comment: This doesn't answer why `std::isinf` does not work. Can you explain that? Thanks!

Comment: It really should — I'm calling it a MSVS/Dinkumware bug.

Comment: @DanielDarabos unfortunately I can't explain why other than it's a bug I had to use a MS macro `_finite` and `_isnan` in my case as I'm using VS2008