# How to double a float/integer within a user input string in C?

Tags: c

I'm sorry in advance because I'm fairly new to programming and some things in my code will probably look like utter nonsense! I'm not entirely sure if I'm using `atoi` right.

I'm trying to create a program that splits a user input sentence into single words and doubles the number(float/integer) if a user inputs one.
For example, `I have 3 cats` would come out as:

```
I
have
6
cats
```

My program right now is able to split the sentence, but I can't get the integer to double. Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char sentence[100];

    printf("Enter a sentence to split: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", sentence);
    char *pch;
    int y;

    y = atoi(sentence);
    printf("After splitting:\n", sentence);
    pch = strtok(sentence," ");
    while (pch != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

And my output so far:

```
Enter a sentence to split: Hi, I have 7 cats.
After splitting:
Hi,
I
have
7
cats.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Do you want a specific solution for this case or rather a generic one?

Comment: `atoi()` converts a string to an integer.  You are calling it at the beginning of your program on the entire sentence, not on a single word (token).  Do you really expect the entire sentence to be an integer, or just one word of it?  Put your `atoi()` inside the loop that processes each word (token).  Another thing to consider: How do you know if the token is an integer or not?  See man [atoi](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi).

Comment: @Bluth, I would recommend you check my answer and say if this is what you need or something else.

Comment: Is an *integer* strictly a sequence of digits or are `+2`, `-3`, `0x20` OK?

Comment: @chqrlie, I believe I just need any number >= 1, decimals and all, if that makes sense. I apologize for not being specific about what I needed.

Comment: @Bluth: you did mention *integer*, so decimals should not be OK.

Comment: @chqrlie, yeah sorry I just looked back at the example and realized there were decimals, I apologize.

Comment: @Bluth: I updated the answer for the floating point case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler version with a test for all digit numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
     char sentence[100];
     char *pch;

     printf("Enter a sentence to split: ");
     if (!fgets(sentence, sizeof sentence, stdin))
          return 1;

     printf("After splitting:\n");
     for (pch = strtok(sentence, " \n"); pch != NULL; pch = strtok(NULL, " \n")) {
         if (pch[strspn(pch, "0123456789")] == '\0') {
             printf("%d\n", atoi(pch) * 2);
         } else {
             printf("%s\n", pch);
         }
     }
     system("PAUSE");
     return 0;
}
```

If you want to parse floating point numbers too, you could use this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
     char sentence[100];
     char *pch, *pend;
     double value;

     printf("Enter a sentence to split: ");
     if (!fgets(sentence, sizeof sentence, stdin))
          return 1;

     printf("After splitting:\n");
     for (pch = strtok(sentence, " \n"); pch != NULL; pch = strtok(NULL, " \n")) {
         value = strtod(pch, &pend);
         if (*pend == '\0' && isfinite(value)) {
             printf("%g\n", value * 2);
         } else {
             printf("%s\n", pch);
         }
     }
     system("PAUSE");
     return 0;
}
```

Note the test for `isfinite()` to avoid recognizing `inf` and `nan` as numbers.

NOTE: `isfinite` is part of C99, it is not supported by VisualStudio 12, but more recent versions do support it.  For this older version, use `_finite()` defined in `<float.h>`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using VS 12 and I don't think it supports "isfinite()" as I've tried to add different libraries but can't seem to get it to work. Do you happen to know any way around this?

Comment: `isfinite()` is part of Standard C. Did you include `<math.h>`?

Comment: Yes I included it. I googled it and apparently it is not part of "<math.h>" or "<cmath>" on a version of VS 12. I'll try it on a different version and make sure it works for me. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: It is a bug in VisualStudio 12.0.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580168/stdisfinite-on-msvc and https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783412/isnan-and-isfinite-support-does-not-exist-in-math-h-or-cmath .  For a specific fix, use `_finite(x)` defined in `<float.h>` or upgrade your VisualStudio to a more recent version.

Comment: @Bluth: can you please upvote the answer you accepted?

Answer (score 0):

For the split part I would recommend this version, it is easier to understand (considering that you've learned the `for` way of working). It does the same thing, but helps you organize your code.

```
char *p;
int i;
    for(p = strtok(sentence, " "); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, " "))
    {
        int isNumber = 1;
        for(i = 0; i < strlen(p); i ++)
        {
            if(!isDigit(p[i])
            {
                isNumber = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isNumber == 1)
        {
            int number = atoi(pch);
            number *= 2;
            printf("%d\n", number);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s\n", p);
        }
    }
```

For the number, I would recommend using the `atoi` function. [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm) you have a good reference.

To solve your problem, first of all, you need to check every single word you get. For example: You take it word by word and see if the "word" contains ONLY digits. If it contains only digits, you can use `atoi` to convert it to a number, multiply it by 2 and print the result.

On the other hand, if you find a char that is NOT a digit, you have letters or any other characters in your word, so it is not a word so you simply print that as it is.

Comment: good idea to use a `for` loop.  You should use `isdigit((unsigned char)p[i]))` -- there is a missing `)`.

Comment: Yes, but if the char overflows, it will take the module, if you use special chars. Thanks for the tip, it's a good observation.

Comment: no it is not supposed to do that, because it is defined for all values of `unsigned char` and the value `EOF`.  Taking the module creates a collision between `EOF` and `'\377'`, typically `ÿ` in iso-latin1.  The glibc uses an array of 384 entries to handle both signed and unsigned char arguments but this is still incorrect for `'\377'`, and it does not mask the int argument, so any sufficiently large argument will crash the program (I checked it does for 1000000).  Darwin uses a less efficient approach with an explicit test: it considers all values outside `0..127` to have no properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example, even if it's not really precise. Basically, we need to find out whether our current string is a number or not. In this case, I just tried to get the first element of the current string, and tried to determine if it's numeric or not.

Of course, if you want to be *really* sure, we need to iterate the string and check every char, if it is a number or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char sentence[100];

    printf("Enter a sentence to split: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", sentence);
    char * pch;
    int y;
    y = atoi(sentence);
    printf("After splitting:\n", sentence);
    pch = strtok (sentence," ");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        if(isdigit(pch[0]))
        {
            int number = atoi(pch);
            number *=2;
            printf("%d\n",number);
            pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
            continue;
        }
        printf("%s\n",pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: What if the user input is this:
I have 7a cats? This will crash. pch[0] is digit, but a is not digit.

Comment: @SimplyMe Indeed. It depends on how robust the answer has to be for OP. I edited my post to consider this.

Comment: I doubt that your code would catch that. You need to check everything.

Comment: @SimplyMe: how would the program crash? it would just ignore the trailing `a`.

Comment: @SimplyMe No, it doesn't. But I gave OP a hint on how he could do it

Comment: @Sossenbinder: this should work, yet you could remove the initial `atoi(sentence)`, and it is better to pass an `unsigned char` to `isdigit()`, use `isdigit((unsigned char)pch[0])`.

Comment: @chqrlie, yes, it will ignore it, but 7a is not a number, so you shouldn't double it. It's to subjective. It depends mostly on what OP needs.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for getting back so late! I appreciate all the help! I've added to my code and moved the "atoi" part into my loop just like you guys have shown in all of your replies. I looked up "isdigit()" and it won't work if a user inputs a float like 2.5 or something so how do I go about changing that? Also, @SimplyMe, you're right, I don't think 7a should be doubled. I believe I just need any number >= 1, decimals and all. I apologize for not being specific about what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another (more compact) answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int is_numeric(char *s)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        if (!isdigit(s[i]))
            return 0;
        ++i;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    char sentence[255];
    char *pch;

    printf("Enter a sentence to split: ");
    if (!fgets(sentence, sizeof(sentence), stdin)) {
        return 1;
    }
    sentence[strcspn(sentence, "\n\r")] = 0; /* Strip newline */

    pch = strtok(sentence, " ");
    while (pch != NULL) {
        if (atoi(pch)) {
            printf("%d\n", 2 * atoi(pch));
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", pch);
        }
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    return 0;
    /* system("PAUSE"); */
}
```

The key is that atoi will return 0 for a non-numeric argument.

Comment: interesting!  but it does not handle `7a`.  You might also remove the definition for `y` and protect the buffer with `if (scanf("%99[^\n]", sentence) != 1) return 1;`

Comment: Another idea for a compact version with a test for valid numbers: `char *p; if (strtol(pch, &p, 10) && !*p)`