# Prevent "Float-point invalid operation" exception?

Tags: c++, double

I am using Visual C++ to load binary data into `float`, like this:

```
  double dValue;
  memcpy(&dValue, lpData, sizeof(dValue));
```

For normal cases, this will work properly. However, for some rare cases, when binary data are corrupt, the `dValue` will be invalid and any further operations on it will cause “Float-point invalid operation” exception.

I check the `dValue` in debugger and it displays as `-1.#QNAN00000000000`.

To prevent the exception, I need to verify the `dValue` after it is loaded from the binary data. I try to use:

```
  if (_finite(dValue))
  {
   … do some tasks…
  }
```

But still the invalid `dValue` will cause `_finite` function to raise a `Float-point invalid operation` exception. Although `_finite(dValue)` will return 0 properly, the exception will be allocated in memory. Even if I deallocate it. Too many allocate/deallocate will still exhaust the system resources.

Therefore, is there a way to detect the validity of a double value without raising any exceptions?

Comment: in Standard C++ there is no way. Perhaps you could check the IEEE754 spec and code up something , that's likely to work.

Comment: If your compiler supports C++11, you should be using `std::isfinite` from `<cmath>`.  See [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite) for more info.

Comment: @paddy that still wouldn't solve the problem

Comment: This is just an argument against using binary data formats. It's much easier to determine validity of lightweight-parsable text-based file formats, like xml or yaml.

Comment: Could be a sledge-hammer to crack a nut, but there is this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dougste/2008/11/12/random-and-unexpected-exception_flt_divide_by_zero-and-exception_flt_invalid__operation/  -- I agree with the suggestion to use text representation.  Binary requires manual validation, and is not even portable, since the IEEE754 does not specify endianness.

Comment: `_finite()` is just checking for _valid_ finite values. Your problem is harder than this: a bit pattern that's not a valid number for the fpu, which (I believe) is invoking a trap handler. You can catch such fpu traps. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2k2f2t.aspx. Also, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9676k6h.aspx for setting up fpu modes including handler invocation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14582105/995714

Comment: @Gene what are invalid bit values? I know NAN and INF but they are valid bit patterns

Comment: I'm not an IEEE fp expert, but believe e.g. that denormalized numbers cause exceptions depending on how the control word is set.

Comment: Does simply trying the operation and then catching and handling the floating point exception (if it occurs) count as a way to detect validity?

Answer (score 1):

I would have expected that [`std::isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) would do what you need and do it most efficiently. If that is not the case for your implementation on your platform, but you feel comfortable assuming that floating point numbers use IEEE 754 format, it is not hard to write those functions yourself.

```
inline constexpr bool
isnan(const std::uint32_t bits) noexcept
{
  constexpr std::uint32_t exponent = UINT32_C(0x7f800000);
  constexpr std::uint32_t mantissa = UINT32_C(0x007fffff);
  return ((bits & exponent) == exponent) && ((bits & mantissa) != 0);
}

inline constexpr bool
isnan(const std::uint64_t bits) noexcept
{
  constexpr std::uint64_t exponent = UINT64_C(0x7ff0000000000000);
  constexpr std::uint64_t mantissa = UINT64_C(0x000fffffffffffff);
  return ((bits & exponent) == exponent) && ((bits & mantissa) != 0);
}
```

Implementing `isfinite` is even simpler, you only have to check that `(bits & exponent) != exponent`. To implement `isnormal`, check that `((bits & exponent) != exponent) && ((bits & exponent) != 0))`. Note that zero is not “normal” by this definition.

Note that the functions operate on integral types. This is intentional. Your code would `fread` the bytes into an integer, you pass the integer to the functions to determine whether it represents “not a number” and (only) if it doesn't, you `memcpy` the bytes into a floating-point type.

Comment: Another way to test for NaN with IEEE floating-point types is `a != a`. It looks silly, but NaN values **never** compare equal. However, it's possible that an overly smart compiler would optimize out a test that can only have one result; in that case it might be necessary to do a bit of indirection to fake out the optimizer.

Comment: @PeteBecker The idea was to test for NaNs *before* converting the bits to a floating-point type so to avoid the FPU overhead the OP was facing.

Comment: Yup, I overlooked that in your answer. Nevertheless... <g>